# How to create a .docx file and not a .doc word using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ms-word, docx

I am using:

```
var header = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' "+
    "xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' "+
    "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>"+
    "<head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML to Word Document with JavaScript</title></head><body>";
    var footer = "</body></html>";
    //@ts-ignore
    if(ev.target.id === "screenword"){
      this.setState({
        typeOfPrint: "screenword",
      }, () => {
        var sourceHTML1 = header+document.getElementById("spage").innerHTML+footer;
        var source1 = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(sourceHTML1);
        var fileDownload1 = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(fileDownload1);
        fileDownload1.href = source1;
        fileDownload1.download = this.state.PPName+'.doc';
        fileDownload1.click();
        document.body.removeChild(fileDownload1);
```

To create a doc file but want to create a docx. I've searched and cannot find any guidance on how to update this code.
I'm trying to avoid external libraries as much as possible.

Comment: Are you creating this from a node app, web page or other platform?

Comment: Hi John - it's SharePoint framework. It uses React as a framework if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using an external library such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx for this.
The page above includes examples using this from a webpage.

Comment: Hi John - yeah I found that but I'm trying to avoid external libraries as much as poss. I'll update my question.